# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) on VPS

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I was able to login to my VPS until yesterday but now I am not. I think I fudged up by not logging out of my session (by typing 'exit') but closing my laptop instead.

Any ideas about how can I regain my access?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: [su] would be more appropriate, imo.